# directories missing, only the home folder showing?

Tags: gnome-panel, menu, home-directory

in gnome classic, in the places menu, only the home folder is listed, yet the videos, pictures etc folders are actually present in the home older and in the side panel

does anyone how to fix this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into whatever folder you want to show up in places and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: edit file .gtk-bookmarks in your home folder and put your folders there:

```
gedit .gtk-bookmarks
```

As an example:

```
file:///home/yourname/Documents
file:///home/yourname/Images
file:///home/yourname/Downloads
```

Comment: thats the odd thing, .gtk-bookmarks is as you you suggested already, yet they dont show up in places, and not in docky either but they exist in the homefolder and in nautilus sidebar

Comment: its ok, I figured it out, I had a look at another post on here by someone that wanted to customize what folders appeared in the places menu. turns out, you go into whatever folder you want to show up in places and pres ctrl + d. solved :)